# Proper memory management for handling a NSMutableArray retained property

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties

I'm wondering if I am managing the memory of an Array correctly.  Below I use this array with a tableView, so I want to keep it around for the life of the ViewController.  Since I create it as a property I'm a little confused on the retain count and how to handle it since I'm alloc'ing it in the code.  Below is how I currently have it coded.

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
```

in .m

```
self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//fill with object I'm going to be using throughout the life of the viewController

- (void) dealloc {
   [mutableArray release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will leak your array if you're doing it that way. because your property is set to retain, `self.mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is the same as `mutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];`.

So change it to

```
self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS will do memory management by itself. Here is [Apple Arc Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). There is also an excellent condensed information about memory management from [Mikeash Friday Q&A blog](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

Comment: Not if you are targeting older versions as well.

Comment: Correct. But you can also see if you have target older OS versions. Here are some stats that might throw some light. http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper

Comment: ARC is available back to iOS4, so unless you're targeting iOS3, you can (and should) still use ARC.